# Need for Speed Most Wanted not working after update from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wine, games

The game was working great on Ubuntu 14.04 but after upgrading to 16.04, it doesn't work anymore.
Here's the backtrace

```
Unhandled exception: invalid float operation in 32-bit code (0x7eb11542).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7eb11542 ESP:0033f3f0 EBP:0033f578 EFLAGS:00210297(  R- --  I S -A-P-C)
 EAX:001681f8 EBX:7eb62a90 ECX:00168210 EDX:00000000
 ESI:0001002e EDI:0001002e
Stack dump:
0x0033f3f0:  00020042 00000022 0033f504 f75bcc5e
0x0033f400:  00000005 0033f540 00000040 7db98820
0x0033f410:  00001000 00000000 00000000 0033f40c
0x0033f420:  00000001 0033f430 0000004c 00000000
0x0033f430:  f75bec29 7bce05bc 00000040 7bc40cb3
0x0033f440:  0033f488 f75bf0a8 00000040 7bc863af
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7eb11542 in gdi32 (+0x61542) (0x0033f578)
  1 0x7e03e67a in winex11 (+0x1e679) (0x0033f598)
  2 0x7e06dff7 in winex11 (+0x4dff6) (0x0033f6a8)
  3 0x7eacecb6 in gdi32 (+0x1ecb5) (0x0033f6d8)
  4 0x7eb085b1 in gdi32 (+0x585b0) (0x0033f7d8)
  5 0x7eb20ec4 SelectObject+0x113() in gdi32 (0x0033f848)
  6 0x7eabefe0 in gdi32 (+0xefdf) (0x0033f888)
  7 0x7eabf1fa CreateCompatibleDC+0x189() in gdi32 (0x0033f8d8)
  8 0x7e8eda00 in user32 (+0x1d9ff) (0x0033f9a8)
  9 0x7e8eeefd in user32 (+0x1eefc) (0x0033fa28)
  10 0x7e8f1929 LoadImageW+0x318() in user32 (0x0033fb58)
  11 0x7e8f217e LoadImageA+0x17d() in user32 (0x0033fc78)
  12 0x7e8f22d3 LoadIconA+0xa2() in user32 (0x0033fcc8)
0x7eb11542: fldz
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (101 modules)
PE    400000-  a78e4e   Export          speed
PE    a80000-  cca000   Deferred        d3dx9_26
ELF 7a800000-7a932000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a932000   \               opengl32
ELF 7b400000-7b7ef000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7ef000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcfe000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc20000-7bcfe000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c003000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7cfa1000-7cfad000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7cfad000-7cfbb000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7cfbb000-7cfc5000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7cfc5000-7cfea000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7cfea000-7d6a4000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF 7d6a4000-7d6c5000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7d6c5000-7d6d7000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7d6d7000-7d6dd000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7d6dd000-7d6f8000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7d6f8000-7d6fb000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7d6fb000-7d6ff000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7d6ff000-7d71b000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7d71b000-7d71e000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7d71e000-7d78d000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d904000-7d93b000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7d96c000-7d973000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d973000-7d97e000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d980000-7d988000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7d988000-7d98c000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7d98c000-7d990000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7d990000-7d9ad000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7dc87000-7dcb1000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dcb1000-7dd61000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7ddbe000-7de07000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7de07000-7de32000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7de32000-7de4b000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7de4b000-7de5e000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7de5e000-7de6b000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7de6b000-7de77000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7de77000-7de7e000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7de7e000-7de85000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7de85000-7deab000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7deab000-7dff6000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dff6000-7e00b000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e00b000-7e0a1000   Dwarf           winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7e020000-7e0a1000   \               winex11
ELF 7e0a1000-7e0dd000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e0b0000-7e0dd000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e0dd000-7e0f6000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7e127000-7e150000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e130000-7e150000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e150000-7e17f000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e160000-7e17f000   \               netapi32
ELF 7e17f000-7e1a1000   Deferred        tapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e190000-7e1a1000   \               tapi32
ELF 7e1a1000-7e25c000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7e1b0000-7e25c000   \               winmm
ELF 7e25c000-7e2ab000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7e260000-7e2ab000   \               dsound
ELF 7e2ab000-7e2d0000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e2b0000-7e2d0000   \               imm32
ELF 7e2d0000-7e34b000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e2e0000-7e34b000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e34b000-7e616000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e360000-7e616000   \               shell32
ELF 7e616000-7e69c000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e620000-7e69c000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e69c000-7e7e3000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6b0000-7e7e3000   \               ole32
ELF 7e7e3000-7e7fe000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7e7f0000-7e7fe000   \               dinput8
ELF 7e7fe000-7e8bb000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e820000-7e8bb000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e8bb000-7ea1c000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8d0000-7ea1c000   \               user32
ELF 7ea1c000-7ea98000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea30000-7ea98000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ea98000-7ebbe000   Dwarf           gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eab0000-7ebbe000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ebbe000-7ecf7000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7ebd0000-7ecf7000   \               wined3d
ELF 7ecf7000-7ed35000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7ed00000-7ed35000   \               d3d9
ELF 7ef35000-7ef48000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef48000-7ef55000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef55000-7ef70000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef70000-7ef7a000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7ef7a000-7efcf000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efd0000-7efd4000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7efd4000-7efe7000   Deferred        shfolder<elf>
  \-PE  7efe0000-7efe7000   \               shfolder
ELF 7efe7000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f73f0000-f73f4000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF f73f5000-f73fa000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f73fa000-f75b0000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f75b0000-f75cd000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f75f1000-f75f5000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f75f6000-f75ff000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF f75ff000-f77c9000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77cb000-f77f0000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77f3000-f77f4000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) C:\Program Files\R.G. Mechanics\Need for Speed - Most Wanted\speed.exe
    00000028    1
    00000027    2
    00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    00000020    0
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001b    0
00000021 explorer.exe
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.9.14 (Staging)
    Platform: i386
    Version: Windows XP
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.6.0-040600-generic
```

Comment: Did you try reinstalling wine and the game?

Comment: @B.Turan Yes, many times with different versions of wine

Comment: Naheel, I have exactly same problem, but found no solution yet :( Did you report the bug to the wine team?

Comment: @B.Turan yes, I did

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, PlayOnLinux does not work, so I found the alternative to solve the problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437380/ubuntu-22-04-how-to-run-an-exe-file-by-the-desktop-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

> Did you try reinstalling wine and the game? – B. Turan 22 hours ago
>   @B.Turan Yes, many times with different versions of wine – Naheel 18 hours ago

In that case, I would sincerely suggest sticking with 14.04, till an expert (I am not one :) dedicates some time to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the speed.exe file in steam as a non steam game.
After that you can enable proton and it will run.

For my computer, it ran at a stable 60 frames per second with max graphics & Vsync.

For more on how to add & use proton you should check a steam play guide.
Then add the exe file.
I suggest using proton experimental.

The widescreen patch can be added by the launch parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. I didn't know it's now on steam. I had it installed from the old installation CD back when the game was new.
Anyway, it has been working well for me in newer versions of wine. Here's the history if anyone is interested https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=41080